# How to slice a pandas dataframe at a regular interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I am new to python and I have a list of five climate data replicates that I would like to separate into individual replicates.  Each replicate has a length of 42734, and the total length of the data frame (df) is 213,674.

Each replicate is separated by a line where the first entry is “replicate”.  I have shown the titles of each column of data above the separating line.

```
Index   year    Month   Day Rain    Evap    Max_Temp
42734   Replicate   #   2   nan     nan      nan
```

I have tried the following code, which is extremely clunky and as I have to generate 100 climate replicates, is not practical.  I know there is an easier way to do this, but I do not have enough experience with python yet to figure it out.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
# Import replicate .txt file into a dataframe
df=pd.read_table('5_replicates.txt',sep=r"\s*"                                 
                 ,skiprows=12,engine='python',header=None,                     
                 names =['year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Rain', 'Evap', 'Max_T'])  

len(df)
i = 42734
num_replicates = 5

## Replicate 1
replicate_1 = df[0:i]          
print "length of replicate_1:", len(replicate_1)

# Replicate 2
replicate_2 = df[i+1 : 2*i+1]    
print "length of replicate_2:", len(replicate_2)

# Replicate 3
replicate_3 = df[2*i+2 : 3*i+2] 
print "length of replicate_3:", len(replicate_3)

# Replicate 4
replicate_4 = df[3*i+3 : 4*i+3] 
print "length of replicate_4:", len(replicate_4)

# Replicate 5
replicate_5 = df[4*i+4 : 5*i+4] 
print "length of replicate_5:", len(replicate_5)

Any help would be much appreciated!
```

Comment: Are you looking for a succinct version to solve this problem? If so, you're almost there. Just exploit the pattern in your own code for the multiples of `i` by utilizing a looping construct and storing the "replicates" into a list instead of individual variables.
You can try to code it yourself to start with. If you need help with the actual codified solution let me know and I can post it on here.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 100 replicates? Do you mean 100 different files or 100 parts of the dataframe instead of the 5 parts in your code?

Comment: Hi, Instead being 5 replicates, I mean that there will be 100.  I am trying to write a for loop for this, but I can't work out how to increase the slice each time.

Comment: I have streamlined the code to this:

Comment: Replicates = {}
    for k in range(num_replicates+1):
        for j in range(num_replicates):
            Replicates['Replicate{0}'.format(k)] = df[j*i+j : k*i+j]              
But it only gives me the last replicate and the earlier ones are empty.

Comment: you do not need two loops. All you need is this:

`for k in range(num_replicates): replicates['Replicate{0}'.format(k+1)] = df[k*i : (k+1)*i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
## create the example data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':pd.date_range(start = '2016-01-01', end='2017-01-01', freq='H'),  'rain':np.random.randn(8785), 'max_temp':np.random.randn(8785)})
df.year = df.year.astype(str) #make the year column of str type

## add index at which we enter replicate. 
df.ix[np.floor(np.linspace(0,df.shape[0]-1, 5)), 'year'] = "Replicate"

In [7]: df.head()
Out[7]:
   max_temp      rain                 year
0 -1.068354  0.959108            Replicate
1 -0.219425  0.777235  2016-01-01 01:00:00
2 -0.262994  0.472665  2016-01-01 02:00:00
3 -1.761527 -0.515135  2016-01-01 03:00:00
4 -2.038738 -1.452385  2016-01-01 04:00:00
```

Here, I just to the following. 1), I find the indexes at which the word "Replicate" is featured and record those indexes into dictionary `idx_dict`. 2) create a python `range` for each block that essentially indexes which blocks rows are in which replicate. 3) finally, I assign the number of a replicate to each block though once you have the range object, you don't really need to do this.

```
#1) find where the word "replicate" is featured
indexes = df[df.year == 'Replicate'].index

#2) create the range objects
idx_dict = {}
for i in range(0,indexes.shape[0]-1):
    idx_dict[i] = range(indexes[i],indexes[i+1]-1)

#3) set the replicate number in some column
df.loc[:,'rep_num'] = np.nan #preset a value for the 'rep_num' column

for i in range(0, 4):
        print(i)
        df.loc[idx_dict[i],'rep_num'] = i
#fill in the NAs because my indexing algorithm isn't splendid         
df.rep_num.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Now, you can just subset the `df` as you please by the replicate number or store portions elsewhere.

```
#get the number of rows in each replicate:
In [26]: df.groupby("rep_num").count()
Out[26]:
         max_temp  rain  year
rep_num
0.0          2196  2196  2196
1.0          2196  2196  2196
2.0          2196  2196  2196
3.0          2197  2197  2197


#get the portion with the first replicate
In [27]: df.loc[df.rep_num==0,:].head()
Out[27]:
   max_temp      rain                 year  rep_num
0  0.976052  0.896358            Replicate      0.0
1 -0.875221 -1.110111  2016-01-01 01:00:00      0.0
2 -0.305727  0.495230  2016-01-01 02:00:00      0.0
3  0.694737 -0.356541  2016-01-01 03:00:00      0.0
4  0.325071  0.669536  2016-01-01 04:00:00      0.0
```

Comment: indexes = df[df.year_rep == 'replicate'].index
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-40-b6d5789be4ce>", line 1, in <module>
    indexes = df[df.year_rep == 'replicate'].index

  File "C:\Users\whitee1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 763, in wrapper
    res = na_op(values, other)

  File "C:\Users\whitee1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 718, in na_op
    raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")

TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code,  I tried to run it and I got the error above.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Emma, unfortunately, without at least a piece of your `df`, it's hard to determine what's wrong. That's why on StackOverflow, it is common to ask a question with either a sample of the `df` or a fitting example thereof. You don't have a `year_rep` column in your `df` so naturally, `df.year_rep` does not exit and running a boolean operation doesn't work. try `df.year == 'Replicate']` instead.

Comment: @Emma, I updated the code to make it more consistent with your example, try the above chunks, see if they work.